# Array Average Calculator

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to call these methods in the main method; however, the list of numbers is coming out as random letters and symbols as well as the average is not correct. I am trying to correct this issue without using any type of complex Java coding:

[image: Test Results]

```
package averagewitharrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageWithArrays {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] numbers = numberArray();
    double average = getAverage(numbers);
    printAverage(numbers, average);

}

public static double[] numberArray() {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] numberArray = new double[10];
    int i = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter 5-10 numbers: ");
    numberArray[i] = scnr.nextDouble();

    return numberArray;
}

public static double getAverage(double[] numberArray) {

    double average = 0;
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        total = total + numberArray[i];
    }

    average = total / numberArray.length;

    return average;
}

public static void printAverage (double[] numberArray, double average) {

    System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + numberArray + " is " + average + ".");    
}

}
```

Comment: You need a for before `numberArray[i] = scnr.nextDouble();`

Comment: The reason you get `0.5` is your array contains one `5` and nine `0`(s).

Comment: What do I need before that line of code? @retatu

Comment: There is no loop

Comment: @TrippKinetics Within the main method?

Comment: Anywhere, as far as I see.

Comment: `for(i < numberArray.length; i++){numberArray[i] = scnr.nextDouble();}`